# Using JS to determine range slider background widths

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome, webkit

I'm trying to control range slider track background widths using jQuery. I'm left scratching my head as to why the background doesn't seem to match the position of the slider however.

You can see the working page here: https://qh.brightchoicemarketing.com/hosting/cloud-vps-hosting/
(View on Chrome or any other Webkit browser)

Here is my code:

```
// .chrome styling
    $( 'input' ).on( 'input', function( ) {
        var x = document.getElementById("cpu").max;
        var x = document.getElementById("ram").max;
        var x = document.getElementById("ssd").max;
        console.log(x);
        y = this.value - 1;
        console.log(y);
        var percentWidth = ((y / x) * 100);
        console.log(percentWidth);
        $( this ).css( 'background', 'linear-gradient(to right, #da0266 0%, #00aeff '+percentWidth +'%, #eef1f8 ' + percentWidth + '%, #eef1f8 100%)' );
    } );
```

I am logging the values to console and the percentages appear to be correct. I next thought perhaps I had set a manually offset to move the slider thumb but I haven't and the background seems to go from too small to too large as you move the slider thumb from left to right (this makes me think it's a multiplier issue...).

Is my maths correct? I subtract 1 from the slider value to deal with the "0" position and then generate the percentage width that the slide thumb should be at.

EDIT:
I am adding custom values to all of the sliders apart from the first one (this is to ensure they show what the user is actually selecting before pushing to the store):

```
// Output value for CPU range slider
var sliderCPU = document.getElementById("cpu");
var outputCPU = document.getElementById("valueCPU");
outputCPU.innerHTML = sliderCPU.value;

sliderCPU.oninput = function() {
  outputCPU.innerHTML = this.value;
}

// Set and output custom values for Memory range slider
var valuesRAM = [0,"256 MB","512 MB","1 GB","2 GB","3 GB","4 GB","5 GB","6 GB","7 GB","8 GB","9 GB","10 GB","11 GB","12 GB"];

var sliderRAM = document.getElementById('ram'),
   outputRAM = document.getElementById('valueRAM');
sliderRAM.oninput = function(){
    outputRAM.innerHTML = valuesRAM[this.value];
};
sliderRAM.oninput();

// Set and output custom values for SSD range slider
var valuesSSD = [0,"10 GB","20 GB","30 GB","40 GB","50 GB","60 GB","70 GB","80 GB","90 GB","100 GB","200 GB","300 GB","400 GB","500 GB"];

var sliderSSD = document.getElementById('ssd'),
   outputSSD = document.getElementById('valueSSD');
sliderSSD.oninput = function(){
    outputSSD.innerHTML = valuesSSD[this.value];
};
sliderSSD.oninput();
```

Comment: what do you mean by the background doesn't match the slider? the gradient background is following the slider fine for me in Firefox. I updated your question for Chrome - seems to be an issue in Chrome

Comment: Thank you, yes it is a Webkit browser issue. Affects Safari as well.

Comment: Do you have `background-size` set correctly? Do not use `auto`

Comment: I have it set to `cover`, doesn't seem to make a difference though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `background-size: 105% 100% !important` to this selector:

```
input[type="range"] {
        outline: none; 
        transition: background 450ms ease-in;
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        cursor: pointer;
        border-radius: 16px;
        height: 15px;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25), inset 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
        background-size: 105% 100% !important
    }
```

Seems to work for me in Chrome and Firefox

Comment: The "Processor" slider is still exhibiting the issue though. Think it's the calculation?

Comment: You're right, it's strange why only 1 is affected. Is there anything unique about that slider? It is known that webkit requires both values of `background-size` to be set to a fixed value when dealing with widths/heights.

Comment: It's the only slider I am not adding custom values to, I'll add this to the main question.

Comment: After playing around with the settings a little bit more, I set the max number of values for the "Processor" slider to 14 and the background began to fit perfectly. I then realised that no matter which slider I was changing, the x value would always equal 14. I think maybe because I am setting x 3 times in the same script without any conditional statements...

Comment: Finally fixed it! I didn't realise, but I was selecting 'input' and applying the styles. I changed this to select individual inputs by their IDs and it's all working now! In general, your answer was the actual fix to the problem and so I've marked it! Thank you very much!